# Can anyone explain for me this method in 1990 IMO inequality

Tags: inequality, proof-explanation

In the **IMO Shortlist 1990** , I read the **Solution** for the inequality **Problem** and I saw this :

**Problem** : Let $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{R}^+$ and $ab+bc+cd+da=1$.Prove that:
$\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}+\frac{b^3}{c+d+a}+\frac{c^3}{a+b+d}+\frac{d^3}{a+b+c}\geq \frac{1}{3}$

**Solution** : By AM-GM inequality

$\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}+\frac{b+c+d}{18}+\frac{a}{6}+\frac{1}{12}\geq \frac{2}{3}a$

Do the same thing:

$LHS\geq \frac{a+b+c+d}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$

Besides: $ab+bc+cd+da=(a+c)(b+d)$ so

$(a+b+c+d)^2 \geq 4(ab+bc+cd+da)=4\rightarrow a+b+c+d \geq 2$

So the inequality is proved.

I can't understand this step: $\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}+\frac{b+c+d}{18}+\frac{a}{6}+\frac{1}{12}\geq \frac{2}{3}a$

How can they know what will be used for AM-GM?Thanks a lot.

Comment: The condition that $ab+bc+cd+da = 1$ is a slight red herring.    
What we actually need and use, is that $S = a+b+c+d \geq 2$.   
By relaxing the constraint, we've actually simplified the inequality to $ \sum \frac{a^3}{S-a} \geq  \frac{S^2}{12} \geq 1/4$. This is a standard inequality (for IMO participants) with numerous approaches (AM-GM, CS, Jensens, tangent line, etc).

Comment: Nice Point. BTW : In your Comment , @CalvinLin , 1/4 == 1/3 , a typo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(A) Proof Crux :**
$\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}+\frac{b+c+d}{18}+\frac{a}{6}+\frac{1}{12} \geq \frac{2}{3}a \tag{1}$

You can think that this is AM-GM like :
$(A+B+C+D)/4 \geq \sqrt[4]{ABCD} \tag{2}$
Where : $A=\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}$
& $B=\frac{b+c+d}{18}$
& $C=\frac{a}{6}$
& $D=\frac{1}{12}$

Plug-in these values into **(2)** & take 4th root & move the Denominator up to get **(1)** & move "forwards".

**(B) How did these values turn up ? What was the motivation ?**
Proof requires terms with $a^3$ Numerator & $b+c+d$ Denominator Cyclically. When we want to get $a$ , eliminating the other unknowns , we can multiply by Denominator & by $a$ to then take 4th root. We also require a Constant.
Proof writer would have tried this :
$\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}+\frac{b+c+d}{k_1}+\frac{a}{k_2}+\frac{1}{k_3} \geq 4\sqrt[4]{\frac{a^3(b+c+d)a}{(b+c+d)k_1k_2k_3}} \tag{3}$

Eventually , what we want to get though **(3)** will then have to make :
$2/3=4/\sqrt[4]{k_1k_2k_3} \tag{4}$
Proof writer might have got various Solutions to **(4)** & choose this :
$(k_1,k_2,k_3)=(18,6,12) \tag{5}$

Proving the Crux uses this **(5)** & things work out.

Proof writer would have tried alternatives too , something like this :
$\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}+\frac{b+c+d}{k_1}+\frac{1}{k_2} \geq 3\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3(b+c+d)}{(b+c+d)k_1k_2}} \tag{6}$
It might have worked out , though getting $(k_1,k_2)$ to satisfy **(6)** might have been harder , giving complicated values , hence this was not used.

That motivation is not given , we have to work "backwards" to figure out that.

Comment: nice! Thank you

Comment: 1/ A much better explanation for the values of $k_i$ is that they are determined by the equality condition (conditional on our choice of terms). Equality holds at $(1/2, 1/2, 1/2, 1/2)$, and thus we need $(1/8)/(3/2) = (3/2)/k_1 = (1/2)/k_2 = 1/ k_3$.    $\quad$ 2/ Likewise for the alternative that you suggested. From this POV, it explains why we're simply "subtracting" a/6 from both sides.

Comment: Nice Point ! I did not check further than listing the Criteria & the Alternative , @CalvinLin , thank you for sharing that Point ! There are more Alternatives. Proof writer did not give the motivations on why this Alternative was the choice.

Answer (score 0):

Another way.

By Holder and AM-GM we obtain:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a^3}{b+c+d}\geq\frac{(a+b+c+d)^3}{4\sum\limits_{cyc}(b+c+d)}=\frac{(a+c+b+d)^2}{12}\geq\frac{\left(2\sqrt{(a+c)(b+d)}\right)^2}{12}=\frac{1}{3}.$$

Comment: It looks like Titu's lemma, thanks!

Comment: This is a nice alternate Proof , but OP "knows" the Proof & wants Explanation , not new Proof.

Comment: That's okay, because this solution is more natural than the original solution!

Comment: @Prem Yes, I know. But this proof so ugly and not natural, so I want to show another way.

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát We are thinking by the same words!

Comment: Yes , the Original Proof [ where @LụcTrườngPhát wanted Explanation ] uses "unnatural" Numbers which are not addressed. Your Proof overcomes that shortcoming !